# python code is not giving output, can any body take a look, what may I have missed

Tags: python

It is not giving output, as expected, which says" {friend} is my friend", when {friend} is a string.
And "you are not a name.......," when {friend} is a string.

```py
Friends=["ankit","kanishk","manish","vansh","tanmay",34]
for friend in Friends:
      if friend is int:     
            print(f"you are not a name, you are a number {friend}")
      elif friend is str:
            print( friend.title()+" is  my friend.")
```

Comment: Hint: look at the `type()` function. 34 is 34, but the data type of 34 is integer.

Comment: also look at `isinstance`

Answer (score 1):

```
Friends=["ankit","kanishk","manish","vansh","tanmay",34]
for friend in Friends:
      if type(friend) is int:
            print(f"you are not a name you are a number which is {friend}")
      elif type(friend)  is str:
            print( friend.title()+" is  my friend.")
```

you should add the 'type()' function for friend. friend's type is int or str.

Comment: I didn't expect, that someone will give an answer. I am a mechanical engineer, who wants to get coding skill.
The coding community is really helpful. I really appreciate your time
Thank you.

Comment: you should know everyone try to help each other here. good luck to you! you are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

You can use isinstance like below,

```
Friends=["ankit","kanishk","manish","vansh","tanmay",34]
for friend in Friends:
      if isinstance(friend, int):     
            print(f"you are not a name, you are a number {friend}")
      elif isinstance(friend, str):
            print( friend.title()+" is  my friend.")
```

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is checking the value as `int` and not the datatype of it. To check the datatype we have to use `type()`.

```
>>> 34 is int
False
>>> type(34) == int
True

Friends=["ankit","kanishk","manish","vansh","tanmay",34]
for friend in Friends:
      if type(friend) == int:     
            print(f"you are not a name, you are a number {friend}")
      elif type(friend) == str:
            print( friend.title()+" is  my friend.")
```

Output:

```
Ankit is  my friend.
Kanishk is  my friend.
Manish is  my friend.
Vansh is  my friend.
Tanmay is  my friend.
you are not a name, you are a number 34
```